# Include a component multiple times, without repeating all inputs and outputs in Angular?

Tags: angular

Imagine list 1 and list 2: both list include the same `app-item-card` component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <!-- list 1: items -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
        <app-item-card (item)="item"
          [isSelected]="item.selected"
          [selectedClass]="'is-selected'"
          (selected)="select(item)"></app-item-card>
    </div>

    <!-- list 2: favorite items -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
        <!-- same component app-item-card -->
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent() {
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;
}
```

How can I include that component twice, **without repeating** all the inputs, outputs, classes etc..?

I know I can make another component named `ItemListComponent` for this purpose, but I wonder if there is a way to do it without that.

Comment: Hint:  the component shouldn't be responsible for *retrieving* the data.  It should be responsible for *displaying* the data.

Comment: @Makoto see my edits, if you are talking about making another component in the middle. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean communicate two or more components without input decorator?

Answer (score 2):

You can place your list logic inside `<ng-template>`, reference it, and then render it using `*ngTemplateOutlet` directive as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <ng-template #listRef>
      <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
        <app-item-card (item)="item"
                      [isSelected]="item.selected"
                      [selectedClass]="'is-selected'"
                      (selected)="select(item)"></app-item-card>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- list 1: items -->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listRef"></ng-container>

    <!-- list 2: favorite items -->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listRef"></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent() {
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;
}
```

You can also provide the context to the template (`items$` in your case) as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <ng-template #listRef let-items$="items$">
      <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async)">
        <app-item-card (item)="item"
                      [isSelected]="item.selected"
                      [selectedClass]="'is-selected'"
                      (selected)="select(item)"></app-item-card>
      </div>
    </ng-template>


    <!-- list 1: items -->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listRef; context: ctx"></ng-container>

    <!-- list 2: favorite items -->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listRef; context: ctx"></ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent() {
  ctx: any;
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ctx = {
      items$: this.items$
    };
  }
}
```

Please also refer to the `NgTemplateOutlet` directive official [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).